# NextJS breakpoints stop hitting after page refresh or code change in vscode

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, next.js

I run yarn dev on my nextjs app and connect to it via vscode using the following:

```
  {
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Next: Chrome",
        "url": "http://localhost:3000",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
```

This works great but as soon as I refresh the page or change a bit of code the breakpoints stop hitting.

Comment: also happening to me

Comment: to me as well...